# Difference in calling __init__ and __new__ by super()

Tags: python

I'm learning how to use the super() function, but I find some question.
For example:

```
class Parent:
    def __new__(cls):
        return object.__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Child(Parent):
    def __new__(cls):
        c = super(Child, cls).__new__(cls)
        return c

    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
```

And here is my question: Why do I need to pass the *cls* to `__new__()` called by `super()`, but I don't need to pass the *self* to `__init__()` called by `super()`?

Thanks for your help!